# find out time number of steps in algorithm based on input size

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose you run a O(log n) algorithm with an input size of 1000 and the algorithm requires 110
operations. When you double the input size to 2000, the algorithm now requires 120 operations. What is
your best guess for the number of operations required when you again double the input size to 4000?

Comment: O.o hmmmm, what the? :O

Comment: One hint: O(log N) means c * log N; Now solve that equation; c remains constant for both algo runs.

Answer (score 4):

The Big-O notation is used to indicate the runtime of the algorithm with respect to the input size in the worst-case. It does not predict anything about the actual number of operations. It does not take into account the low order terms and the constant factors.

Comment: Note that if "it does not predict anything about the number of operations", then it wouldn't predict anything about the runtime either.

Comment: Big O gives an asymptotic upper bound on the running time of an algorithm. Therefore you are right that it does not predict anything about the exact runtime. And that's why I said worst-case in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an additive constant, corresponding to run-time overhead, in the solution. The following presumes that the result is Ɵ(log n) rather than just O(log n).

[image]

You could go on and explicitly solve for the constants if you wanted to make generalized predictions, but doing so based on two points would be pretty dubious.

Answer (score 0):

Let `f(n)` be the estimation of the number of operations, just put your question into equation :

```
f(n) = c * log(n) // O(log n) algorithm
f(1000) = 110
f(2000) = 120
f(4000) = ?
```

Find `c` and you'll find your answer. But of course, it would only be a *best guess* estimation based on the given data and limiting behavior of `f`.

It won't be an accurate prediction for multiple reasons :

- The big O notation only gives your the limiting behavior of the algorithm complexity, not the actual complexity formula.
- The number of operation may strongly depends on the nature of the data, not just the multiplicity `n`.
- The limiting behavior is calculated in a particular case of possible data (usually worst case).

Comment: We cannot calculate the number of operations for an O(log n) algorithm like that. O(log n) is not equal to log n. We don't know the constants nor do we know about the lower order terms.

Comment: @Kunal It's just an approximation, an order of magnitude, not the *actual* number of operation.